# Can fuel and brake lines touch?

Tags: honda, accord, fuel-line, brake-lines

I have a 2001 Honda Accord. I just installed nylon fuel lines and in certain places they touch the brake lines.  Also, in the engine bay, a rubber fuel line touches the tube coming out of the brake fluid container. Can I just leave the fuel lines as they are, or should I use some sort of barrier to protect them from the heat of brake lines?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brake lines themselves aren't going to have any heat to speak of. The heat generated at the brakes themselves may travel a little bit up the lines, but not much, and then not much heat at all. There should be no worries about heat from the brake lines.

The only thing I'd worry about is wear from the metal contact, but that's not going to be of an issue. Rubbing may cause some sort of wear, but as long as the hose isn't touching any sharp corners (like body seams), that shouldn't happen, either.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks, that's a relief!  I had read somewhere that break lines get really hot and I thought I might have to redo a lot of work.